# How to find the first few roots of all the equation stored in table in mathematica

Tags: plotting, equation-solving, functional-style

```
(*This program is about finding the roots of the equations stored in \
table t1. Now  i am trying to find the roots of these equation in one \
single run.*)
ClearAll["Global`*"]

a = 1/(2*b^3)
t1 = Table[
   a*(((Sin[b*(1 - i)]*Sin[b*i])/Sin[b]) - ((
       Sinh[b*(1 - i)]*Sinh[b*i])/Sinh[b])), {i, 0.01, 0.5, 0.01}];

t1[[1]]
(* (
Csc[b] Sin[0.01 b] Sin[0.99 b] - 
 Csch[b] Sinh[0.01 b] Sinh[0.99 b])/(2 b^3) *)

f[x_] := t1[[50]] /. b -> x;

p = Plot[{f[x], 0.}, {x, 0.1, 50}, PlotPoints -> 350]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
intersections = Graphics`Mesh`FindIntersections[p] // Chop
(* {{7.8527, 0}, {14.136, 0}, {20.4191, 0}, {26.7031, 
  0}, {32.9867, 0}, {39.2698, 0}, {45.5524, 0}} *)

Labeled[Show[p, Frame -> True, Axes -> False, 
  Epilog -> {PointSize[.025], Red, Point[intersections]}], 
 Style[#, 20] &@Column[N[intersections, 10], Frame -> All], Right]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I tried by doing manually it works but it is too time-consuming. I want to somehow put in a loop such that first few roots of the equations in the table can be found.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to solve for `b` as a function of `i` in the following equation:

```
eqn = a*(((Sin[b*(1-i)]*Sin[b*i])/Sin[b])-((Sinh[b*(1-i)]*Sinh[b*i])/Sinh[b])) == 0;
eqn //TeXForm
```

> $\frac{\csc (b) \sin (b (1-i)) \sin (b i)-\operatorname{csch}(b) \sinh (b (1-i)) \sinh (b i)}{2 b^3}=0$

Instead of using [`FindRoot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindRoot) on your equation for each value of `i`, it is much more robust to use [`NDSolveValue`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NDSolveValue). To do so, we need an initial value:

```
i0 = Values @ NSolve[(eqn /. i->.1) && 0 < b < 20, b][[All, 1]]
```

> {4.22637, 7.6313, 11.0505, 14.4793, 17.9123}

Next, we need to create an ODE (replace `b` with `b[i]` and differentiate), and use [`NDSolveValue`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NDSolveValue):

```
sol = NDSolveValue[
    {D[eqn /. b->b[i], i], b[.1] == i0},
    b,
    {i, $MachineEpsilon, .5},
    PrecisionGoal->16
];
```

Here is a plot:

```
Plot[sol[x], {x, 0, .5}]
```

[image]

The nice thing about this approach is that we avoid jumping curves as can occur when you use FindRoot independently on each value of `i`. For example, the following plot superimposes the `roots` found by @HenrikSchumacher in his answer:

```
Show[
    Plot[sol[x], {x, 0, .5}, PlotStyle->LightBlue],
    ListPlot[
        MapThread[Thread[{##}]&, {Range[.01,.5,.01], roots[[All, ;;5]]}],
        PlotStyle->Blue
    ]
]
```

[image]

Notice the intervals where there are no dark blue dots on the light blue line. This is where the `` Graphics`Mesh`FindIntersections ``/[`FindRoot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindRoot) approach switched curves.

Finally, finding an initial point using [`NSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NSolve) is rather slow, but solving the ODE is extremely fast. One could speed up the initial point computation by using a [`FindRoot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindRoot) based technique instead.

Answer (score 6):

This could work for you.

The data

```
Y = 2*10^11;
Iyy = 8.333*10^-6;
L = 4;
k = 10^12;
a = 1/(2*b^3);
t1 = Table[
   a*(((Sin[b*(1 - i)]*Sin[b*i])/Sin[b]) - ((Sinh[b*(1 - i)]*Sinh[b*i])/Sinh[b])), 
   {i, 0.01, 0.5, 0.01}];
```

This function takes a function, plots it (`PlotPoints -> k`) and detects the intersection of the plotted graphs with the x-axis (note that internally, the graphs are polygonal lines that lead to rather coarse approximation to the actual roots). It is sufficient to use very small amounts of `PlotPoints` since we will refine the roots later with `FindRoot`.

```
estimator = {f, k} \[Function] Graphics`Mesh`FindIntersections[
     Plot[{f, 0.}, {b, 0.1, 50}, PlotPoints -> k, 
      PlotRange -> {-0.1, 0.1}]
     ][[All, 1]];
```

And this is the code that detects the roots very precisely. Note that we can convince `FindRoot` to apply Newton's method to all points in  `estimator[f, 2]` at once. Drawing the function `f` from the list `t1` and using a `Table`, this produces a list `roots` whose i-th entry is the list of roots of `t1[[i]]`.

```
roots = Table[b /. FindRoot[f, {b, estimator[f, 10]}], {f, t1}];
```

That's it. For highly oscilating function, `estimator[f, 10]` might miss some roots. In that case one can try `estimator[f, k]` with higher `k`.

Comment: tricky, where did you find  the infomation concerning `Graphics\`Mesh\`FindIntersections[]` ???

Comment: @UlrichNeumann I used ``Graphics`Mesh`FindIntersections`` solely because the OP used it. The rest is common sense: `Plot` generates `Graphics` objects wherein the curves are stored as `Lines`, i.e. polygonal curves. Since `Graphics`Mesh`FindIntersections[]` is handed over only the `Graphics` object but not the expression for the plotted function, the best it can do is determining the intersections of the polygonal lines. However, creating the `Plot` is not a particular efficient way to get initial guesses for `FindRoot`...

Comment: Thanks! Looking for some additional information I tried `??Graphics\`Mesh\`*` MMA returned a long list of possibilities but no further documentation.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher  actually there a small typo in the code a=k/2*b^3, if I plot the function i get a lot of straight lines. I may end up with so many spurious roots. and another thing is you didn't give information about how to put in the loop.

Comment: @VijayKumarS Look up `Table` in the docs *eyeroll*.

Comment: @UlrichNeumann You know, the issue with undocumented functions is that they are undocumented... ;o)